# Custom exception from LINQ Select?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using `Select` to identify the elements from list B corresponding to the elements of list A. I require that every item in list A has a corresponding element in list B. If this requirement is not met, I want to throw an exception that includes information about the element of A that was not matched.

This is what I've come up with. Is there a more succinct way to do this, other than writing an extension method?

```
var selected = listA.Select(a =>
{
    var b = listB.FirstOrDefault(o => /* test correspondence with a */);
    if(b == null)
    {
        /* throw exception with information about a */
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't throw from the Select, I'd select invalid elements and throw with a message about all of them. If you want only the first invalid one you could just use FirstOrDefault() and check if that is null.

Comment: @C.M.Your last sentence seems to describe exactly what I did.

Comment: No, it describes doing it outside the Select. You're doing it inside.

Comment: @madreflection You mean returning nulls from `Select` and then checking if the result contains any nulls? If I do that, I'll lose information about which element of A had no match.

Comment: Not if you do an outer join. Use the result of that to test any elements (or just the first) that don't match from B and throw with info about A.

Comment: I think the suggestion is something like this (I'm using a `.Length` comparison as the validation for example): `var errors = listA.Where(a => listB.All(b => a.Length != b.Length)); if (errors.Any()) throw new Exception($"Errors encounterd with {errors.Count()} objects:\r\n - {string.Join("\r\n - ", errors)}");`. One problem with this would be that it iterates the list twice if there are no errors. The benefit is that you see all the errors if there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 7.0, you can throw exceptions from the ternary (`?:`) and null-coalescing (`??`) operators, which simplifies your existing code.

I don't know what your comparison criteria are, so I just made up a `.Length` comparison for this example:

```
var selected = listA.Select(a => listB.FirstOrDefault(b => a.Length == b.Length) 
    ?? throw new Exception("Problem with an item in listA: " + a));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do an outer join of `listB` to `listA`, you can find any elements missing in B and report the corresponding A elements.

```cs
var temp = from a in listA
           join b in listB on a.AID equals b.AID into outerB
           from b in outerB.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new { a, b };

var firstUnmatched = temp.FirstOrDefault(t => t.b is null);
if (firstUnmatched != null)
{
    // use firstUnmatched.a to indicate which one doesn't match in B
    throw new Exception(/* ... */);
}

var allUnmatchedA = (from t in temp
                     where t.b is null
                     select t.a).ToList();
```

Using `allUnmatchedA` above, you can create an exception with the full list of objects, or take the IDs from it and report just those.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a HashSet to validate it in a clean and efficient way.

```
// I require that every item in list A has a corresponding element in list B.
var listA = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
var listB = new HashSet<int>(new[] { 1, 3 });

listA.ExceptWith(listB);

//now listA contains only elements that didn't match listB (the value 2)
```